# How to migrate a MySql database to a SQL Server database safely?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration

I have a MySql database (tables + data) I wish to move to a Sql Server 2005 database keeping data intact (I know there will be some minor differences in data types).

I'm looking for any tutorial, tool, article that will help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin with Microsoft's guide for migration: [Migrating to SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/migration.aspx)
, and then look at Microsoft's specific guide for mySQL to SQL Server: [Guide to Migrating from MySQL to SQL Server 2008](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/C/2/7C20B070-BFF8-44B4-BD7D-1B03DF50F924/MigrateMySQLtoSQLServer2008.docx)

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work because it's SQL Server 2005. I updated my question

Comment: Ok thanks to your link I found another one that just did it: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=69739c8c-ac82-41de-b9e6-8fa5ae2594d9&displaylang=en